# Trying to get property of non-object in PHP

Tags: php

I'm working with PHP and get error message:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\gmbr\fw\model\UserModel.php on line 234

This is my code:

```
# Static user
public static function is_admin()
{
    return self::$auth->admin?true:false; // <<- This line 234
}

public static function username()
{
    return self::$auth->username;
}
```

Comment: Can you show more of your code. This is not enough to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Probably what's going on is that the $auth object isn't initialized yet when your method is called.

Use a var_dump(self::$auth) to see what's going on.

If this is the case, I would use a Singleton design pattern with $auth, Running a self::getAuth() instead of self::$auth.

Comment: i change self::$auth to self::getAuth() and get fatal error.

$auth object is initialized with: 

# Authentication
private static $auth = null;